# Substring extraction with multiple options

Tags: string, stata, matching, fuzzy-comparison

I have a variable in Stata in my dataset that looks like this:

```
city
Washington city
Boston city
El Paso city
Nashville-Davidson metropolitan government (balance)
Lexington-Fayette urban county
```

And I want it to look like:

```
city
Washington
Boston
El Paso
Nashville-Davidson
Lexington-Fayette
```

"city," "county," and "urban county" are the only three words that follow after a city name.
In other words, I want to extract the substring from left to the space before either city, county, or urban.

The only way I can think of approaching this using subinstring:

```
replace city = subinstr(city, " city", "", .)
```

I don't think, however, that I can add multiple options here.

Answer (score 3):

I used `subinstr` to replace the desired words with empty strings, and `trim` to remove additional spaces.

```
input str60(city)

"Washington city"
"Boston city"
"El Paso city"
"Lexington-Fayette urban county"
"Audacity"

end

gen     wanted = subinstr(city,"urban county","",1)
replace wanted = subinstr(wanted," county","",1)
replace wanted = subinstr(wanted," city","",1)

replace wanted = trim(wanted)

list

     +----------------------------------------------------+
     |                           city              wanted |
     |----------------------------------------------------|
  1. |                Washington city          Washington |
  2. |                    Boston city              Boston |
  3. |                   El Paso city             El Paso |
  4. | Lexington-Fayette urban county   Lexington-Fayette |
  5. |                       Audacity            Audacity |
     +----------------------------------------------------+
```

Edit: As suggested, I have incorporated a leading space so that places with "city" in their name (e.g. Audacity) are not inadvertently replaced. The same for "county" (although this seems less likely).

Comment: This looks good so long as “city” does not occur as part of a name. “Salt Lake City” is safe, but are there any smaller settlements with names like Audacity? Cautious code would not remove it unless it was the last word in the string.

Comment: I think this could be fixed by searching for the string " city" (with a leading space). I'll test it and update my answer.

Comment: `subinword` would be helpful .

Answer (score 3):

`split` could be a way.

```
split city, parse(" city" " urban" " county") limit(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think using regular expression replacement to search for a space followed by a relevant substring would be the most flexible option here. For example:

```
clear
input str60(city)

"Washington city"
"Boston city"
"El Paso city"
"Lexington-Fayette urban county"
"Audacity"
"Salt Lake City city"

end

gen clean_city = ustrregexra(city, "\s(city|county|urban county)","")


     +----------------------------------------------------+
     |                           city          clean_city |
     |----------------------------------------------------|
  1. |                Washington city          Washington |
  2. |                    Boston city              Boston |
  3. |                   El Paso city             El Paso |
  4. | Lexington-Fayette urban county   Lexington-Fayette |
  5. |                       Audacity            Audacity |
  6. |            Salt Lake City city      Salt Lake City |
     +----------------------------------------------------+
```